# Is there a word or couple words for when you meet someone you have always wanted to meet?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage, synonyms

I don't necessarily mean in a romantic way more like meeting your favorite musician or comedian or something like that, just really anyone you have always wanted to get connected with. I was thinking of the phrase "special someone" but I am looking for something that might not have to do with anything romantically. Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. thank you.

Comment: Do you want a phrase for the *event* of meeting someone you've always wanted to? Your attempt with "special someone" instead describes the *person* that you've always wanted to meet. Please clarify what you're looking for exactly.

Comment: Either works. I am looking for either a phrase for the event of meeting someone or a word or phrase along the lines of this sentence: I just met the person ive always wanted to meet. Is there a word for that person or a phrase/word for the event of meeting that person @cigien

Comment: *Finally* . . .

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any word or phrase other than "meet your heroes".

And it's usually prefaced with "Never".  And there's a good reason. The world is full of stories about people who met their heroes, and were disappointed.

https://thoughtcatalog.com/justin-hook/2012/09/12-reasons-you-should-never-meet-your-hero/

https://www.suggest.com/celebs/1609972/25-people-reveal-why-the-phrase-never-meet-your-heroes-couldnt-be-more-true/

Answer (score 1):

You could call it a "dream come true." Or you could say that by meeting this person you can cross another item off your [bucket list](https://www.joincake.com/blog/bucket-list-origin/).

You could also say meeting him or her was [kismet](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/kismet); that is,
.good fortune, fate, or God's will.

Another possibility is to call it a happy [happenstance](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/happenstance).

Comment: There are lots of phrases such as "once in a lifetime experience", "dream made reality", etc, which are a bit more general in scope but all denote something rare but good; but it's not clear exactly what the OP wants.

Answer (score -1):

Idol, Hero, Inspiration, Muse. Take the phrase, "never meet your heroes". Same idea, other side of the coin on that one though

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).